# OneDrive PUT failing with error 503

Tags: android, onedrive

Since yesterday (20/05/2016 0800 UTC) I have been trying to upload a file in OneDrive through the Android SDK 1.1.5 but every time the request (PUT https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/folder_id/children/file_name/content) returns with a response code 503 Service Unavailable. Am I doing something wrong or is the API really down for so long?

Also is there a link where we devs can check the status (whether it's healthy or not) of the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in OneDrive Android SDK 1.2.0. See: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android/issues/79